# numpy m x n combination grid with m and n array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, nm

i was wondering if there is an easy way to do this:

```
a = 
[[1,2],[3,4]]

b =
[[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

turning into this:

```
c = 
    [[[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]],
    [[3,4], [3,4], [3,4]]]
d = 
    [[[5,6], [7,8], [9,10]],
    [[5,6], [7,8], [9,10]]]
```

so i can do this:

```
c - d
```

i've already tried using np.meshgrid, but it was a really clunk:

```
indexes_b, indexes_a = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(a.shape[0]),
    np.arange(b.shape[0])
)

c = a[indexes_a]
d = b[indexes_b]
c - d # works
```

Comment: `np.subtract.outer(a,b)` or `a[None]-b[:,None]`

Answer (score 4):

Use `broadcasting`:

```
>>> a[:, None] - b
array([[[-4, -4],
        [-6, -6],
        [-8, -8]],

       [[-2, -2],
        [-4, -4],
        [-6, -6]]])

>>> c - d
array([[[-4, -4],
        [-6, -6],
        [-8, -8]],

       [[-2, -2],
        [-4, -4],
        [-6, -6]]])
```

Comment: I was also computing the real `c` and `d` in case it's also needed: `c = np.tile(a[:,None], (1,b.shape[0],1)) ; d = np.tile(b[None], (a.shape[0],1,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = [[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]

c = [[li]*len(b[0]) for li in a]
d = [[li]*len(a) for li in b]

print(c)
print(d)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).